# Unable to get the text from div class - selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

```html
<div class="jss7113 jss7118"><div></div><div class="jss7114">Invalid username or password</div><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label"><i icon="close-circle-outline" title="" class="mdi mdi-close-circle-outline" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button></div>
```

This is what  wrote

```html
        //System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*.jss5107")).getText()); //Get the error message from the Invalid credentials
        //System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class = 'jss7114']")).getText().equals("Invalid username or password"));
        //System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'jss7114']")).getText().equals("Invalid username or password"));
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the class name you're trying to find doesn't exist:

```html
        //System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*.jss5107")).getText());
```

this type of gibberish names for elements usually indicates random attribute values being generated and making your automation relying on those values is a no go because we want our automation to be as solid and low maintenance as possible.
Instead, try to find a better way to locate the element you're looking for.
I could've tried to give you a better locator but it seems like you pasted a part of the HTML code which I can't read it properly (for example there's a div tag that immediately gets closed right after):

```html
        <div class="jss7113 jss7118"><div></div>
```

Please provide a better snippet of this part of the HTML in order for us to help with your question.

If you want to validate the message, you can locate the element by the text within it:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Invalid username or password')]